# Python list - get specific Index for non unique value

Tags: python

I am trying to get the index of specific items in a list as I loop through it.

```py
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 8, 0]
```

If I am iterating through this list and I want the index of each item, not index of the first match, or the indexes for all matches, what is the most elegant way that I can achieve this?

I started off with `list.index()` and then have read a bit about enumerators but neither of these give me exactly what I want. I read something about panda and series, but want to see if I can achieve what I am after with the standard python without packages. I am using Python 3.8.0.

To clarify further I am looking for an elegant solution that gives me the index of the the given element.

So, something functionally similar to

```py
i = 0
list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 8, 0]
for column in list:
    print(column)
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

So each time I observe an object/column in the list, I want its corresponding index (`i` in code above). The code above is not elegant. I think the enumerator language element will give me a list of indexes for the list, or a subset of indexes for the list.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please describe the expected result in detail.  I'm not sure what you intend to supply to this code snippet, and what you want in return.

Comment: How did "enumerators" not work for you?

Comment: I have added more detail to the question. Hopefully it answers all the questions.

Comment: You're looking for `[index for index,item in enumerate(my_list) if item == 0]`. (Do not call a list `list`. It hides the [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes it was sloppy to use the type as the list name. However wouldn’t that code produce a list of the indexes for items that are equal to zero, like so ‘’’[ 0,1,2,3,7] ‘’’ ?

Comment: It indeed does. It's what you get for "each time I observe an object/column in the list, I want its corresponding index".

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the usefulness of enumerate. I see that iterating through each item, the index is given. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe an enumerator is exactly what you're looking for.

```py
value_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 8, 0]
for i, value in enumerate(value_list):
    print(value)
    print(i)
```

This will give you the index of each item as you traverse the list.